# document.elementbyid function not working in div

Tags: javascript, php

I have written a code to change the background as per day time. If i am applying it to whole body, its working fine but when i am trying to put it inside a div,its not working. Please see my code and guide me through the error.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<style>
/*reset*/ h1,h4 {margin:0;}
/* basic styles */
h1 { margin-bottom: 10px; }
div { 
width: 680px;
padding: 10px 25px;
margin: 50px auto;
border-radius: 7px;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4); 
color: #1F1F1F;
}

/* backgrounds */
.day { background: url('http://imgs.mi9.com/uploads/photography/4480/white-clouds-and-          blue-sky_1600x1200_78556.jpg'); }
.sunset { background:   url('http://www.naturewallpaper.eu/desktopwallpapers/sky/1366x768/after-sunset-sky-  1366x768.jpg'); }
.night { background: url('http://images2.layoutsparks.com/1/159946/moon-girl-night- sky.jpg'); }
#ship{width:60%; height:100px; border:#30C 1px solid;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="ship">
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getHours();
if (n > 19 || n < 6)
 // If time is after 7PM or before 6AM, apply night theme to ‘body’
  document.elementById('ship').style.backgroundImage.className = "nighta";
else if (n > 16 && n < 19)
  // If time is between 4PM – 7PM sunset theme to ‘body’
  document.elementById('ship').style.backgroundImage.className = "sunset";
else
  // Else use ‘day’ theme
  document.elementById('ship').style.backgroundImage.className = "day";
});

</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use `document.getElementById` not `document.elementById`

Comment: Why not use the jQuery library as it's intended? `$("#ship")`

Comment: _What_ is the error? Also, this is not a place for "guiding you through the error". You need a conversational venue for that, such as a chat room or discussion forum. Stack Overflow is a Q&A, more like a FAQ.

Comment: no error is being showed. The div where image needs to be displayed is empty.

Comment: @ Austin - not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, quite the number of errors here - both in spelling and basic approach.

They are:

1. you need to use `document.getElementById`
2. you need to set `document.getElementById('ship').className` (not `document.getElementById('ship').style.backgroundImage.className` )
3. you need to ensure that you change the name of the css class to `nighta` or change your code so that it sets it to `night`

Do this, and if you're in a night-time period currently, you'll see a black background with a few clouds.

Like this:
[image]

[edit: code added]

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style>
/*reset*/ h1,h4 {margin:0;}
/* basic styles */
h1 { margin-bottom: 10px; }
div { 
width: 680px;
padding: 10px 25px;
margin: 50px auto;
border-radius: 7px;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4); 
color: #1F1F1F;
}

/* backgrounds */
.day { background: url('http://imgs.mi9.com/uploads/photography/4480/white-clouds-and-          blue-sky_1600x1200_78556.jpg'); }
.sunset { background:   url('http://www.naturewallpaper.eu/desktopwallpapers/sky/1366x768/after-sunset-sky-  1366x768.jpg'); }
.night { background: url('http://images2.layoutsparks.com/1/159946/moon-girl-night- sky.jpg'); }
#ship{width:60%; height:100px; border:#30C 1px solid;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="ship">
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', onPageLoaded, false);

function onPageLoaded()
{
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getHours();
    var className;
    if (n > 19 || n < 6)
        className = "night";
    else if ((n > 16) && (n < 19))
        className = "sunset";
    else
        className = "day";

    document.getElementById("ship").className = className;
}

</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i made the changes that you have mentioned but still result,,, a blank div.

Comment: @Shail - you can't have. I made those changes and it works. Either you've missed something, or your browser belongs in a toilet bowl. I've updated my answer with a working copy. Note I've also removed the reliance on jQuery and I've reduced the size of the code in your js function. :)

Comment: yes its working now.. thanks alot. I hope picture will change with sunrise. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is `document.getElementById('id')` and not what you are using.

Learn more about it at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById)

Comment: ...and then forget about it and use the jQuery functions.

Answer (score 0):

I have commented out the JS codes and underneath each you can see an equivalent in jQuery.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var d = new Date();
  var n = d.getHours();
  if (n > 19 || n < 6)
     // If time is after 7PM or before 6AM, apply night theme to ‘body’
     // document.getElementById('ship').className = "night";
       $("#Ship").toggleClass("night");
  else if (n > 16 && n < 19)
     // If time is between 4PM – 7PM sunset theme to ‘body’
    // document.getElementById('ship').className = "sunset";
       $("#ship").toggleClass("sunset");
 else
    // Else use ‘day’ theme
    // document.getElementById('ship').className = "day";
      $("#ship").toggleClass("day");
});  
</script>
```

**Sources:** [W3Schools - Style backgroundImage Property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundimage.asp), [StackOverflow - Change an element's CSS class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript), [W3Schools - jQuery - Get and Set CSS Classes](http://www.w3schools.com/Jquery/jquery_css_classes.asp)

Comment: @Hamed-- tried but still no result

Comment: @Shail, are you running you file locally? try adding `http:` before your JQuery sources in the head tag!

Comment: its working noe Hamed, thanks alot for your help

Comment: @Shail, please don't forget to accept the proper answer (the green tick)! glad to be of help :)